# Assert(false) not executing

Tags: mocha

I am running a mocha test for a solidity SC.  One of my test function should pass and then, just after that i am calling assert(false), but it is not executing.

```
 it('only manager can call the pickWinner', async () => {
try {
  await lottery.methods.pickWinner().call({
    from: accounts[1],
  });
  assert(false);
} catch (err) {
  assert(err);
}});
```

The test is passing even though I am doing assert(false).

Answer (score 1):

Because you're catching the error in your test.

The idea in Mocha is that exceptions are caught at the framework level, not at the "application" level.

A test fails if it throws an exception to the Mocha framework, and passes otherwise.

Comment: Why the dislike? I think the answer is right

Answer (score 0):

I think we're watching the same udemy course.
There are comments on that lecture:

*"This does not work because assert(false) actually throws an error, so it would always pass."*

The solution suggested in the comments:

```
it('requires a minimum amount of ether to enter', async () => {
    let executed;
    try {
      await lottery.methods.enter().send({
        from: accounts[0],
        value: '100'
      });
      executed = 'success';
    } catch (err) {
      executed = 'fail'
    }
 
    assert.equal('fail', executed);
  });
```